# Are these two integrals equivalent?

Tags: integration

I am trying to figure out if the following integrals are equivalent by some sort of symmetry 
$$f_1(z)=\int_{\max\{-1-z,-1\}}^{\min\{1-z,1\}}\frac{dy}{\pi^2 \sqrt{1-(z+y)^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}}$$
and the following

$$f_2(z)= \int_{\max\{z-1,-1\}}^{\min\{z+1,1\}} \frac{dy}{\pi^2 \sqrt{1-(z-y)^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}}$$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the difference between the two integrands is the change of variable $y\mapsto-y$. Now look at the boundaries of your integrals to check if they match after the precedent change of variables (use the fact that $-\min\left(a,b\right)=\max\left(-a,-b\right)$
  and conversely).

Comment: thanks but that doesnt help in my case right?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that there should be a factor $-1$.